# Stop code execution for user decision when displaying new form

Tags: c#, winforms

My code iterates over a list of names (strings), and then it opens a new window that receives the name as a parameter.

In the window the user needs to check or uncheck a radio button, then clicks on an accept button and then the window closes. After that the loops continues through the next name (string).

The problem is the loop opens all the windows, but I want it to wait until the user clicks the button. How can I do that?

Comment: Wild guess, you are doing myParamForm.Show() when you should be doing myParamForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a newbie mistake of my part. That was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are opening a modeless rather than modal dialog.

You do not specify your UI framework.  For WinForms use

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

rather than

```
myForm.Show();
```